# Domain computer away from domain network isn't performing dns lookup correctly?

Tags: networking, dns

I have a laptop that is not connected to the same network as our domain controller (its out of the office) and it is not resolving DNS correctly.

The DNS server (1.1.1.1) is assigned through DHCP and using nslookup this shows correctly:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\nslookup google.ca
Server: one.one.one.one
Address: 1.1.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: google.ca.ad.domain.com
Address: 72.74.244.38
```

*I've substituted domain.com for our actual domain name along with a dummy IP address above.*

When I ping google.com for example it shows the correct IP address and is able to ping it.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>ping google.com                     

Pinging google.com [172.217.165.14] with 32 bytes of data: 
Reply from 172.217.165.14: bytes=32 time=975ms TTL=52      
Reply from 172.217.165.14: bytes=32 time=685ms TTL=52      
Reply from 172.217.165.14: bytes=32 time=722ms TTL=52      
Reply from 172.217.165.14: bytes=32 time=709ms TTL=52      

Ping statistics for 172.217.165.14:                        
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),   
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:             
    Minimum = 685ms, Maximum = 975ms, Average = 772ms
```

*The long ping times are because this network is on a satellite internet connection.*

I am wondering why our domain is being appended to the NS lookup and why the correct DNS response is not coming through.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nslookup` makes several tries to find the referenced site.
It always begins with the domain name, and only if not found it will try other
possibilities.

What's happening is that your *external* DNS server is responding that they have
an entry for `google.ca.ad.domain.com` and is returning the IP address for the site,
which is correct.

This probably indicates that a DNS server in your
domain is over-ambitious and is set to answer queries to DNS queries
as if it was authoritative to their domain, in this way causing the global DNS server
that delegated that query to accept the answer.

In other words, `nslookup` asks about `google.ca.ad.domain.com`.
Google DNS delegates the query to the DNS server at `domain.com`,
which unfortunately goes and searches for `google.ca` and returns
the right answer to Google DNS. It really shouldn't be doing that.

I believe that your domain's DNS server needs to be set to respond only to queries
for entries it actually has (domain.com, www.domain.com, mail.domain.com, etc.),
not to queries about the entire world.

Comment: the computer is not connected to the domain, its on a separate network.

Comment: It must have been defined as Primary Dns Suffix. See details in `ipconfig /all`.